# Touchevent run false

Tags: android, events, touch, touch-event, motionevent

The Game is, that the user tries to do a ball in a hole.

1.
The touchCounter goes wrong, I want that the user only have 2 tries, when I run that code in my game the user have more tries, what is the mistake?

```
final int MAX_TRY_COUNT = 2;
 int counter = 0;

 @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     float currentX = event.getX();
     float currentY = event.getY();
     float deltaX, deltaY;
     float scalingFactor = 1.0f / ((box.xMax > box.yMax) ? box.yMax : box.xMax);



         switch (event.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

              counter = 2;

    if (currentX >= previousX) {
    deltaX = currentX - previousX;
    ball.speedX += deltaX * scalingFactor;    
   } else if (previousX >= currentX) {
    deltaX = previousX - currentX;
    ball.speedX += deltaX * scalingFactor;  
   } if (currentY >= previousY) {
    deltaY = currentY - previousY;
    ball.speedX += deltaY * scalingFactor;    
   } else if (previousY >= currentY) {
    deltaY = previousY - currentY;
     ball.speedY += deltaY * scalingFactor;
    }




              break;              
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

if (counter >= MAX_TRY_COUNT){
              // Alert message
                return;
             }
            counter++;

         }



     // Save current x, y
     previousX = currentX;
     previousY = currentY;
     return true;  // Event handled
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two variables for handle it.

```
final int MAX_TRY_COUNT = 2;
int counter = 0;
```

In ACTION_DOWN event

```
  If(counter >= MAX_TRY_COUNT){
  // Alert message
    return;
 }
counter++;
```

And remove touch_counter =1 from ACTION_UP

Comment: I edit my question like you telled, but the return from your If(counter....){} become a red underline from eclipse as an error

Comment: Then change to return false;

Comment: I do it, but it not works, I can do more events than 2... another tip? :)

Comment: Remove counter = 2;  from ACTION_DOWN and put my code in the same line. Why you put in ACTION_UP. Yoi should put that in ACTION_DOWN instead of counter =2;